How to create a playlist in LibreELEC 12.0.1
I want to create a playlist in Kodi. However, in the tutorials there is often a "normal playlist", which does not exist. If I try to use the a smart playlist this always stays empty.
I want to create a playlist with some videos, so I can play them in an infinite loop. Is there another option to do this?
Thank you :)
